# Loop through indexes in C

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to look for values in an array that equal to `0` up to a certain index, but the function sets all my previous values to 0; instead of checking for 0s.

`a` is the specified index, and `Mem` is an array of size `100`.

```
for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    if (Mem[i]=0){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to check for `0`s in an array up to a certain index.
If there are any, I need to output an `error`.

Comment: What makes you doubt the code? Any unwanted behaviour observed?

Comment: Yeah, the function sets all my previous values to `0`; instead of checking for `0`s

Comment: Do you want `Mem[a]` included in the check?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, only the values up to `Mem[a]`

Comment: And do you see any part of your code which does something like `Mem[i]=0` ? (Caught me at reading lazily by the way ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch No, nothing like that

Comment: Really not? Look inside the if-condition...

Comment: I got it now, from the answer below. It was the `=` instead of `==` fml

Comment: For better future questions, please study the concept of making a [mcve].

Comment: I will look into that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try it on this question, too. It  might get you out of the negative.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't expose my code. But not to worry about the negative. I learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. They can catch some mistakes like these for you.

Comment: If you think that not being able to expose your code is a problem, then you did not really get the idea of making a [mcve]. Please study more carefully. We actually do not even want to see all your code. Just some similar code with the same problem. Read the link, everything is explained there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (Mem[i]=0)` 
is assigning 0 to each Mem[i].
You are effectively writing 0 to every element of the array.

You need to use the == comparison operator 
  i.e `if (Mem[i] == 0)`

Other than that, you have the right idea.

Comment: Quite nice work for what seems to be your first answer. Check out formatting options for future answers and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    if (Mem[i]==0){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }
}
```

The `=` operator is for assigning a value to a variable.
But `==` is a comparison operator for logical expressions.